# Hibernate mapping of map<object1, List<Integer>>

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hsqldb

So I got a new error and I narrowed it down to 2 classes. I think the mapping for the Map attribute of the "Grouping" class must be wrong. Here is the code:

#### Java Entities

```
public class Grouping {
    private long id;
    private Map<Meal, List<Integer>> mealsCounter;
}


public class Meal implements java.io.Serializable {
    private long id;
    private Grouping grouping;
}
```

#### Hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="data.Grouping" table="GROUPING">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <map name="mealsCounter" table="MEAL" lazy="true" access="field">
        <key>
            <column name="ID" />
        </key>
        <map-key type="data.Meal"></map-key>
        <one-to-many class="data.Meal" />
    </map>
</class>

<class name="data.Meal" table="MEAL">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="grouping" class="data.Grouping" fetch="join">
        <column name="GROUPING" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to persist and object I get the following errorlog:

```
Hibernate: insert into MEAL (NAME, GROUPING, ID) values (?, ?, ?)
756 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -177, SQLState: 23503
756 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK240BC3E3481002 table: MEAL
```

Comment: Did you persist the "Meal" before adding it to the map?

Comment: If there's exactly one Grouping for a given Meal, that means a given Meal will only be in one `mealsCounter` map, and only have one list of counts associated with it. Why not make `mealsCounter` a property of Meal (of type `List<Integer>` then? It would make the mapping less confusing.

Comment: Also, it seems you're trying to store both the Meal entity, as well as the `mealsCounter` mapping in the same table. I'm not sure if this is intentional, but it might also be causing a different table structure than you expect to be generated.

Comment: Lastly, I believe many-to-one mappings are not-null by default. So your Meal must have an already persisted Grouping set.

Comment: I added the list to the meal which worked fine.  Now I tried to add <many-to-one name="grouping" class="data.Grouping" fetch="join" not-null="false"> to the meal mapping but it still didn't work. By definition the meals dont have a grouping when they first are persistet. So how can I solve this problem?